# Blend VS2013 missing HTML Option

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2013, blend

I just installed VS2013 Pro in Office, mostly because of Blend and its HTML Option. Maybe im blind but i cannot find any way to start an application with html like its shown in multiple videos. I must confess that i wanted to "abuse" blend to create prototypes with html.

[image]

There are plenty of nice looking prototyping tools but most of them are web based, which i cannot use. I have Win8, not 8.1.

How can i start a HTML project in Blend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 and Blend-for-VS2013 requires Windows 8.1 to use the "Windows Store App" components (both the XAML and HTML Windows Store areas). Visual Studio **2012** is for Windows 8.0.

You must upgrade to Windows 8.1 or downgrade to Visual Studio 2012.

Blend's HTML design tools are only for WWA (Windows Web Applications, aka "HTML Windows Store Apps") and do not officially work for website projects (which is a shame, imoh).

Disclaimer: I'm a developer at MSFT who worked on Blend.